# can a non-dbo sql server user create a queue in service broker?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, queue, service-broker

we have an application being developed where it is running as the AD user connecting to a service broker enabled SQL Server 2008 database.

We are having trouble granting the right permissions to get the app to work for the specific user, 
(the app creates/deletes queues during its operation) unless we make that user a member of dbo for the database being used for the service broker application.

Is this the only way we can get the app to work, put each user as a member of dbo in the database?

Granting CREATE QUEUE/SERVICE TO user and SELECT on the specfic tables doesnt seem to be enough.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Due to the distributed nature of Service Broker, queues and services should be long lived objects. An application that creates and drops queues and services is very unlikely to act correctly.

That being said, the required permission is RECEIVE to operate on a queue (BEGIN CONVERSATION/SEND/RECEIVE). The user that created a queue is the queue owner and has this permission implicitly. To deliver messages to a target service the initiator service must have SEND permission, but be carefull that identity is established using [Service Broker dialog security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166036%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which is based on certificates. Note though that * within a SQL Server instance* the Service Broker conversation security model will emulate the familiar model of user-id (ie. no certificates are required to establish identity), but is subject to [EXECUTE AS context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187096%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

If you can be more specific about which operation fails, we can be more specific about what permission is required.

Comment: thanks remus, very useful information on the broker security contexts. i will try get some more trace information - at the moment im using sql trace to see the create queue statements, but not much else is shown. is there any other places i should be looking for the service broker info?

Comment: I know this is old but this statement caught my attention: *An application that creates and drops queues and services is very unlikely to act correctly*... isn't it exactly what the `SqlDependency` class in .NET does? SB noob here trying to learn. :D

Answer (score 0):

Create separate schema per user and make the user the owner of that schema. Service broker will create the sprocs and queues in the default schema of the user. This [post](http://kreelbits.blogspot.com/2014/10/microsoft-sql-useful-database-role-for.html) on how to setup service broker permissions may help you: http://kreelbits.blogspot.com/2014/10/microsoft-sql-useful-database-role-for.html